# Xamarin.Forms set focus from mvvm ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

I'm working on a chat application using Xamarin.Forms.

And I want to avoid to hide the keyboard when the Entry loses focus and button Send is clicked.

How can I do it on Android and iOS?

I use XF, full Mvvm without XAML(only C#)

**Updated:**

In page class:

```
private EntrySetBorder _newMessageEntry;
...
_newMessageEntry = new EntrySetBorder
{
    TextColor = Color.Black,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
    Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 5, 0)
};
```

In model class:

```
var entry = CurrentPage.FindByName<EntrySetBorder>("_newMessageEntry");
entry.Focus();
```

}

Comment: So, do you want to keep the focus on entry no matter what?

Comment: I want to set back focus or keep focus on entry when button clicked, but when user tap, on message, for ex., keyboard should hide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved easily by using the `FindByName<>()` function inside the PCL.
This is one way of doing that:

```
Entry myEntry = CurrentPage.FindByName<Entry>("YourEntryName");
myEntry.Focus();
```

You can add that at the end of the click handler of your send button.

#### Edit:

In your case I think your problem is that your entry is set to `private`, so I would suggest either expose it as `public` or expose it using another public property. Two solutions that might work:

```
public EntrySetBorder _newMessageEntry;
...
_newMessageEntry = new EntrySetBorder
{

    TextColor = Color.Black,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
    Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 5, 0)
};
```

And:

```
EntrySetBorder entry = CurrentPage.FindByName<EntrySetBorder>("_newMessageEntry");
entry.Focus();
```

Or you go with this:

```
private EntrySetBorder _newMessageEntry;
...
_newMessageEntry = new EntrySetBorder
{

    TextColor = Color.Black,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
    Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 5, 0)
};
public EntrySetBorder NewMessageEntry => _newMessageEntry;
```

and :

```
EntrySetBorder entry = CurrentPage.FindByName<EntrySetBorder>("NewMessageEntry");
entry.Focus();
```

Please try that :)

#### Edit 2:

After reviewing your code, and testing it, the final way to fix it was by sending the Entry as a parameter in the command you're using, example:

Inside the page you're creating:

```
sendButton.CommandParameter = NewMessageEntry; // We're adding the Entry we want to focus as a command parameter.
```

And inside your PageModel and the command we want to use:

```
public Command SendCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command<Entry>((obj) => //obj here means the parameters we're sending I.E: the entry we set it in the page.
        {
            //The code you want to execute
            Entry entry = obj;
            entry.Focus();
        });
    }
}
```

Note that I used `Entry` because I didn't have all the implementation of your custom entry.

Comment: I don't use event handler. I use mvvm command both data binding.

Comment: I tried. I get error "this element is not in a namescope"

Comment: Could you please show how you're creating your entry? And how did you include the two lines I showed please.

Comment: @Atlantis Updated the answer according to your updated question. Hopefully this works.

Comment: unfortunately, nothing changed. The same exception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135587/discussion-between-paul-karam-and-atlantis).

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how I do, before this I used to do using MessagingCenter

in xaml , you need to give an x:Name to the obj you want to make focus.

```
<!-- PICKER's DEFINITION -->
<DatePicker
    x:Name="Datepicker"
    Date="{Binding SelectedDate, Mode=TwoWay}"
    IsEnabled="true"
    IsVisible="false">
</DatePicker>
```

then you have to make reference to that control in your command parameter on a button or for example in this case I use a toolbar item.

```
<!-- MENU TOOLBAR -->
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem
        Command="{Binding ShowCalendarCommand}"
        Icon="Calendar"
        CommandParameter="{x:Reference Datepicker}" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

then in your vm command :

```
    #region toolbar commands

    public ICommand ShowCalendarCommand => new RelayCommand<Object>(ShowCalendar);

    #endregion

    private void ShowCalendar(Object obj)
    {
        var calendar = (DatePicker)obj;
        calendar.Focus();
        //  MessagingCenter.Send(this, "Calendar");
    }
```